# CodeIgniter page refresh and session issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using CodeIgniter for my website with its session library to store user logins etc.

Recently, things started acting really weird.

1. When I try to load a page, Chrome says "waiting for localhost..." and takes ages to load the page. HOWEVER, when I spam F5 about 5 times, the page just loads instantly. This happens often, but especially whenever I edit a css/js/php file and try to load a page that relies on that file.
2. The session keeps getting destroyed even though I set `$config['sess_expiration']` to `0`, which means it should never expire. I also tried setting it to some high number (a week or so), but that doesn't change anything.

Even though they seem like seperate issues, I feel like they are related. Firstly because they started occurring at the same time, and secondly because the session seems to expire faster when I get more of these refresh bugs.

The problems occur on both my Wamp server and live.

Here are some things that might be helpful:

**Session conig in config.php**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cycleswap';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 604800; // Tried many values for this.
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE; // Doesn't change anything.
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE; // Doesn't change anything.
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 604800; // Tried many values for this.
```

**.htaccess (note that the problem occurred way before I even had an .htaccess file)**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|documents|plugins|scripts|style|database|data|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I saw some similar questions by searching Stackoverflow but none that exactly match my problems. I also tried suggestions posted there but nothing helped.

Comment: When you start a session, can you verify if the data is being added to the sessions table in your database?

Comment: Yes it does appear correctly in the database.